# Slow performance writing to windows registry, using .net SetValue function

Tags: vb.net, registry

We use the .net `SetValue` function to write to the registry.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Until recently, the function took virtually no time to execute.
Suddenly, it take 5 or more seconds to execute, when writing to specific keys in the registry.
When writing to 20 such keys, it causes a problem, a significant delay in the execution of our code.

The project is vb.net windows forms app. target framework 3.5.
We tested in several work stations, windows 7, windows 10.

The code looks like this:

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
Imports System.IO

Dim regkey As Object
Dim sKeyName = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\1\"
Dim sValueName = "1001"
Dim vValueSetting = 0
Try
    regkey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(sKeyName, True)
    regkey.SetValue(sValueName, vValueSetting)
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

The delay is only in the `SetValue` function.

What can explain this behavior?

Comment: Try declaring the `regkey` variable with an explicit type to avoid late binding: `Dim regkey As RegistryKey` - Don't use `Object` if the type of type variable is known. Also, if an exception is thrown in that code (which you don't know since you don't log it) that _could_ also cause a bit of slowdown (however not in the matter of seconds).

Comment: Thanks, 
Declaring as RegistryKey did not help.
Also, there is no exception. I'm debugging the code. step over the SetValue line, takeד 5-10 seconds

Comment: Odd... Can you test this on another computer? I actually don't have any more suggestions give, and I had no luck searching Google about it.